# Did logicists use mathematical entities (in their attempt) to reduce mathematics to logic?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic, frege

> Two concepts F,G are **equinumerous** if there exists a one-to-one
>   correspondence between the objects that fall under F and G.

**Equinumerosity** is one the most fundamental building blocks of Gottlob Frege's attempt to reduce mathematics to logic. Reading the definition, though, this struck me:

*Isn't it problematic that the concept of **one-to-one correspondence** is used prior to defining the notion of **maps-functions**? Or is it preassumed that is a concept familiar through **empirical means?***

If we assume the first, then that would imply we use mathematical entities (not rigorously defined) to explore the nature of mathematics and this seems to me like circular reasoning.

On the other hand, if we assume the last, this would imply that the whole construction of mathematics has some empirical basis, which seem even more counterintuitive.

Could you help me clarify this confusion?

Comment: Although 1-1 correspondence sounds like it uses maps it can be expressed without them. Namely, for every x under F there is a y under G, for every y under G there is an x under F, and different x-s have different y-s. You only need logical connectives, quantifiers and the equality symbol to express all of that in addition to "x falls under F". But we do use non-rigorously defined words to explain what symbols mean and how to manipulate them anyway, so there is no escaping that.

Comment: @Conifold I strongly disagree. "and different x-s have different y-s." presupposes a specific way of choosing ys for xs - that is, a map. "You only need logical connectives, quantifiers and the equality symbol to express all of that" that's not true - bringing dependence into things without a function symbol pushes you into [past first-order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150259/can-we-specify-in-a-first-order-formula-that-a-variable-depends-not-on-all-previ?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Except Frege did not care which order, nor was the notion extant at the time. See e.g. [Heck, The Julius Caesar Objection, p.14](http://rkheck.frege.org/pdf/published/JuliusCaesarObjection.pdf) for a symbolic version of his Hume's principle.

Comment: @Conifold That seems a minor point here - I don't buy that symmetric relations are ontologically simpler than functions - and regardless doesn't address the logical issue I mentioned (the existence of a bijection between two sets can't be expressed in a first-order way).

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is a question about Frege's logicism, how is first-order logic introduced decades later relevant at all?

Comment: @Conifold You wrote "You only need logical connectives, quantifiers and the equality symbol to express all of that in addition" - I don't see how that's true (unless you expand the notion of "logical connective" in such a way as to make the statement essentially trivial).

Comment: It doesn't matter how *I* would or would not expand it, only how Frege did

Comment: @Conifold OK, but I don't see any argument here for what you've claimed. In particular, Heck's approach involves quantifying over relations - which takes us to the issue of whether (symmetric) relations are really ontologically prior to functions in any sense. I just don't see any real avoidance of the function concept here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Frege allows himself to quantify over relations while maintaining that the concept of relation isn't used, or to use three differently named letters while maintaining that the concept  of 3 isn't involved. His "falls under concept" also uses a set theoretic notion, from modern point of view. What "logic" or "real avoidance" means to us today isn't what it meant to Frege, he did not operate under modern standards and conventions.

Comment: @Conifold "Frege allows himself to quantify over relations while maintaining that the concept of relation isn't used" Is there a citation for that? Regardless, the OP asked "Isn't it problematic that [stuff]" rather than "Did Frege find it problematic that [stuff]," so I think these are relevant issues to raise.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I read it as "is it problematic within Frege's way of doing things", not "is it problematic *to us*". Because in the latter case we can just say that logicism failed anyway, and the question is not very interesting.

Comment: Goldfarb tries to explain Frege's way of doing things and defends him against Poincaré's circularity criticisms in [Poincaré against the logicists](https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/185664):"*As Frege warned, there can be an appearance of circularity; but
this appearance is dispelled when one distinguishes uses of numerical expressions
that can be replaced by purely quantificational devices from the
full-blooded uses of such expressions that the formal definition is meant
to underwrite. The former involve no arithmetic, and no mathematical
induction; hence there is no petitio.*"

Comment: Frege "played" with the subtle distinction between the notion of *set* (which is mathematical) and that of [*concept* (which is logical)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#1.3). The difficulties came with the introduction of the [*course-of-value*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#2.1) notion (and the corresponding Basic Law V) that is the extensional counterpart of a concept. Unfortunately, the course-of-value object is very similar to a set and using Law V Russell was able to prduce his well-known Paradox.

Answer (score 2):

Frege considered the notion of functions to be logically primitive and so to be undefinable. He tried to give some elucidations of his idea of functions by saying that functions comprise all and only the unsaturated or incomplete things. So Frege's logicism simply takes functions for granted as it does regarding objects (the complement of functions).

As a remark it should be noted that while many Frege scholars think that the central logical entities for Frege's logicism are extensions of concepts it should be noted that Frege's Axiom V in the *Grundgesetze* is actually about functions. It says that functions have the same *Werthverlauf* or course of value iff they yield the same value for every argument. So functions appear to be of much greater importance to Frege's project than extensions of concepts. This is confirmed by a posthumous piece of Frege's titled 'Was kann ich als Ergebnis meiner Arbeit ansehen?', published after Russell's letter apparently shattered Frege's project. There Frege still accepts a distinction between function and objects but is silent on extensions of concepts.